Determine the distance from a point $P$ to the center of the circle as a function of the radius $R$
Let AB be the diameter of a circle with center O and radius R. On the extension of AB we choose a point P (PB<PA). Starting from P we take a secant that cuts the circle at points M and N (PM<PN), so that PM = AN = R.
Find an equation (3rd degree) that determines the distance from P to the center of the circle as a function of R.
I try
I managed to show that MB is one side of a regular inscribed polygon with eighteen sides.
$\triangle ANO: AN=AO=ON \therefore $ equilateral triangle $
$\angle NPA = \theta \cong \angle BSD \implies \angle BNP = \frac{\theta}{2}$
$\angle ANB=90^o  \implies \angle \theta +\frac{\theta}{2} + 90^o +60^o =180^o \therefore \theta = 20^o $
$\therefore \frac{360^o }{20} = 18$
Let $d = PO$
$PN.PM = PB.PA \implies PN.R=(d-R)(d+R) \therefore PN.R = d^2-R^2$
$d^2 -R^2-PNR = 0$
How do I continue from here?

$PN^2 = R^2+(PB+2R)^2-2R.(PB+2R).cos 60^o \\
PN^2=R^2+PB^2+4PBR+4R^2 -PBR-2R^2\\
PN^2=PB^2+3PBR+3R^2$

Hint: Use cosine rule to find PN^2. You have also derived an expression for PN using power of a point.

@ACB I calculate $PN^2$  but we have an equation and a new variable $PB$

PB=PO-R  (PO is what we have to find.)

You've already done most of the work. As ACB's comment indicates, you can use $\lvert PB\rvert = \lvert PO\rvert - R = d - R$. Somewhat more simply, in your $PN^2 = R^2 + (PB + 2R)^2 - 2R\cdot(PB+2R)\cdot\cos 60^{\circ}$, you could replace $PB+2R$ with $d+R$. In either case, your final equation becomes
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert PN\rvert^2 & = (d - R)^2 + 3(d - R)R + 3R^2 \\
& = d^2 - 2dR + R^2 + 3dR - 3R^2 + 3R^2 \\
& = d^2 + dR + R^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
From your earlier equation, the above result and that $d \neq 0$, we also have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
d^2 - R^2 & = R\lvert PN\rvert \\
(d^2 - R^2)^2 & = R^2\lvert PN\rvert^2 \\
d^4 - 2d^2R^2 + R^4 & = R^2(d^2 + dR + R^2) \\
d^4 - 2d^2R^2 + R^4 & = d^2R^2 + dR^3 + R^4 \\
d^4 - 3R^2d^2 - R^3d & = 0 \\
d^3 - 3R^2d - R^3 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Note that an alternate method to derive \eqref{eq1A} is to use that the line from $N$ to $AO$, meeting at $Q$, is the midpoint of $AO$ and perpendicular to it. Using $\lvert NQ\rvert = \frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}$ and the Pythagorean theorem then gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert PN\rvert^2 & = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}\right)^2 + \left(d + \frac{R}{2}\right)^2 \\
& = \frac{3R^2}{2} + d^2 + dR + \frac{R^2}{4} \\
& = d^2 + dR + R^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Very good as always..thank you my friend

Taking as variable the angle $\angle{DBP}=t$ and taking into account that triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ is equilateral, you do have the attached figure.
Consequently $t=20^{\circ}$ (because $t=30-\dfrac{t}{2}$ and $\boxed{f(R)=2R\cos(20^{\circ})}$
Note.-This result without cubic equation has been verified for several values of $R$.


@peta arantes.-There is really a cubic equation, as you say, because $20= \dfrac{60}{3}$ so you have the cubic $\dfrac12=4x^3-3x$ where $x=\dfrac{\pi}{9}$. My answer simply say that this angle of twenty degrees can be get easily. You are welcome.

Thanks for explanation

Obviously that I wanted to say $x=\cos(\frac{\pi}{9})$ instead of  $x=\dfrac{\pi}{9}$.


Hint:
In figure :
$GN=AN=ON=OM=PM=R$
$PO^2=(PM=R)[PG=2R(1+cos 40^o)]\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$
In triangle PON we have:
$\frac{ON=R}{sin 20^o}=\frac {PO}{sin 40^o}$
$cos 40^o=2 sin 20 cos 20$
$\Rightarrow PO=2R cos 20^o$
$cos 40^o=2cos^2 20^o-1=2(\frac { PO}{2R})^2-1\space\space\space\space\space\space(2)$
Now you need to find $cos 40^o$ in terms of PO and R from this relation and put it in relation (1).
